# Pyautogui cursor not working after seclect a text box and click at other object

Tags: python, debugging, cursor, pyautogui

I'm currently having trouble with pyautogui's cursor

When I execute the code, it click the text box and write text there. But after its done writitng and move to another object I aslo want it to click but the cursor didn't change, make the cursor stay text cursor and it cannot click anything after that despite the cursor moved to the object that I need to click. Pydirectinput didn't work aslo, can anybody help me? Thank you

code here:

```
import random as r
import pyautogui as pg
import pydirectinput as pg2
import time as t
pg.FAILSAFE = False
letter="1234567890QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM"
generated=None
def gen():
    code=''.join(r.sample(letter,12))
    print("Generated code: ",code)
    return code
def redeem():
    pass
def check():
    pass
def mine():
    empty = pg.locateCenterOnScreen('empty.png', confidence=.9)
    redeem = pg.locateCenterOnScreen('redeem.png',confidence=.9)
    codeis = None
    ok = None
    x=None
    print(empty)
    if empty != None:
        print(empty)
        pg.moveTo(empty)
        t.sleep(0.001)
        pg2.click()
        t.sleep(0.001)
        x=gen()
        t.sleep(0.1)
        pg.write(x)
        t.sleep(.1)
        pg2.press('esc')
        if redeem != None:
            print(redeem)
            t.sleep(0.1)
            pg.moveTo(redeem)
            t.sleep(.1)
            pg2.click()
            t.sleep(0.1)
        
    else:
        pass
#main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        mine()
```

[image: cursor here, it stays like this and cannot click that "redeem" button]

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to click on Roblox, there are issues with Pyautogui clicking the mouse in Roblox but i've found a workaround for that:

```
import autoit
    if empty != None:
    print(empty)
    pg.moveTo(empty)
    t.sleep(0.001)
    autoit.mouse_click("left") #Instead of using pyautogui to click, we are gonna use autoit
    t.sleep(0.001)
    x=gen()
    t.sleep(0.1)
    pg.write(x)
    t.sleep(.1)
    pg2.press('esc')
    if redeem != None:
        print(redeem)
        t.sleep(0.1)
        pg.moveTo(redeem)
        t.sleep(.1)
        autoit.mouse_click("left") #Instead of using pyautogui to click, we are gonna use autoit
        t.sleep(0.1)
    
else:
    pass
```

Comment: I tried it but same thing, I had to move my mouse a bit and it only click the text box after that it cannot click anything anymore

Comment: My bad, the script only works when in the roblox menu. I'm trying to find a fix for this